# Rails: error in setup google-api-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, google-api-client

in Rails (rails 4.0.0 rc2, ruby 1.9.3p429), in the Gemfile i've the following line:

```
gem 'google-api-client',  :require => 'google/api_client'
```

and then    bundle install.

In a controller:

```
require 'google/api_client'

class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
      @client = Google::ApiClient.new
   end
end
```

If i go to 127.0.0.1:3000  i've the following error:

```
NameError in PagesController#home
uninitialized constant Google::ApiClient
```

Anyone can tell me how integrate the ruby google api in rails?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart server after `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, i have restarted the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is APIClient.new.

```
@client = Google::APIClient.new
```

You should also set the application name and version number or you get an ugly stdout when run your code. Like so :

```
@client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => "MyApplication",:application_version => "0.1")
```